# how to restore a misbehaving/customised taskbar notification area

Tags: windows-8.1, taskbar

Something went weird with my taskbar notification area - the third party software icons that normally show when I click the little up arrow symbol to "show hidden icons" all disappeared apart from one (which isn't third party - it's part of the O/S). It went from the "normal" case below to the "abnormal" one shown (simulated) below.

[image]

So I selected the "customize" option on that pop-up box in an effort to get them back... and then the little up arrow symbol disappeared completely, and only the previously active icon sat alone directly on my taskbar.

Is there a "restore to factory settings" kind of process for the taskbar notification area? This occurred on a Windows 8.1 64-bit system in case that makes a difference (even though my illustrations are from a Win 7 64-bit system).

The reason the screenshot is simulated is that the icons were all restored by a reboot. Is there any way to avoid the reboot? As it happened, I was remotely connected to a system that had a BIOS boot password on it. I was only lucky enough that someone on site could type the password for me.

Comment: I found where to re-customise back to the default settings - right click taskbar, select properties, and there is a "customise" option for the "notification area". That brings up the window which did the damage... and even allows for a "Restore default icon behaviours". But I'm still back to only one icon where there should be 6-8 of them.

Comment: What do you mean "little up arrow"? Is it the arrow to resize taskbar height?

Comment: No the "show hidden icons" one - could have made that clearer - will do.

Comment: `Restore default icon behaviors` only applied to third-party application, if you want to restore Windows trayicon, go to  `Turn system icons on or off`

Comment: It was all the third party icons that had disappeared. Normal behaviour was restored by reboot - still no idea why they all disappeared.

Comment: Do you mean even you have choose `Show icon and notifications` but still can't display it?

Comment: Exactly - no setting on that customise page made them show up, not even the "restore default icon behaviors". But a reboot did restore them.